# Unable to fetch the property of another classe on the mainwindow.xaml textboxes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am Unable to fetch the property of another classe on the mainwindow.xaml textboxes.In the MainWindow.xaml i am trying to fetch the property value that is defined on the mainwindow.xaml.cs.Here I am successfully fetching the Name Property of ABC class in the first textbox.Details are below:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBox  Text="{Binding Name1}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding class1.Name1}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
```

ABC win = new ABC();
            win.Name1 = "Main Window";
            c1.Name = "Class 1";
            this.DataContext = win;
        }

```
    public class ABC
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public Class1 class1
    {
        get
        {
            return c1;
        }
        set
        {
            c1 = value;
            INotifyChanged("class1");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void INotifyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

**Class1.cs**

```
public class Class1:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no property called `Name1` in `Class1`

Comment: <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding class1.Name1}"/>
    </StackPanel>

Comment: Look at your `Class1` it has 1 property called `Name` so your xaml will have to be `<TextBox Text="{Binding class1.Name}"/>`

Comment: Yes you are right...it done by mistake ..now i make it as you say..but still it is not shows what i want

Comment: Did you fix your `DataContext` like I suggested in my answer?

Comment: sa_ddam213 now my prob has been solved, thanks alot for help.

Answer (score 1):

`Class1` it has 1 property called `Name` so your xaml will have to be `<TextBox Text="{Binding class1.Name}"/>`, and you seem to be setting your `DataContext` to a nested class you can't do that, Nested classes are not supported in xaml.

You will have to add `ABC` as a variable and remove as a nested class

Example:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--You can't bind to a nested class-->
        <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBox  Text="{Binding Name1}"/>
        </StackPanel>-->

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBox  Text="{Binding ABCClass.Name1}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding class1.Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    private ABC _abcClass = new ABC();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        class1.Name = "Class 1";
        _abcClass.Name1 = "ABC Class";
    }

    public ABC ABCClass
    {
        get { return _abcClass; }
        set { _abcClass = value; INotifyChanged("ABCClass"); }
    }

    public Class1 class1
    {
        get { return c1; }
        set { c1 = value; INotifyChanged("class1"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void INotifyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Classes

```
public class Class1 : NotifyBase
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
}

public class ABC : NotifyBase
{
    private string name;
    public string Name1
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name1"); }
    }
}

public class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]